# Help with GSM Module from Telit GM862

Tags: gsm, at-commands

I bought a GM862 module some while ago, I inserted the SIM card and made all the necessary configurations but I always get the:

```
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,2
```

response, which means that is trying to get a network but can't succesfully connect. Now the question is: Do I need to install an antenna in order for it to work? (I didn't buy one because I thought it has an internal antenna.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An antenna is essential if you want to connect to the network! If you look at the unit you will see a tiny coaxial socket marked GSM on the bottom edge, where the antenna needs to be attached. A similar connector marked GPS is on the upper left side, for a GPS antenna. Your Telit distributor should be able supply suitable antennae.

Comment: Thanks, I have notice both connectors but I didn't know if it was necessary ( I was thinking it had a internal antenna )

Comment: You can check the signal strength on most cell modules using the AT+CSQ command.  The first number returned is a signal strength from 0-31 or 99 (the latter means it doesn't have a signal yet).  A value around 6 or 7 is like a single bar on a cell phone; a value around 20 or more is very good, like four bars.